# Regex Expression for Date Format DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm using the following Regex Expression: (1[0-2]|0[1-9])/(1[5-9]|2\d) for MM/YY

I am trying to get this pattern for DD/MM/YYYY but not managing.

Can someone help please :) ?

Comment: What have you actually tried so far?

Comment: can you really not find it by googling? I guarantee it will be in one of first 3 google results if i google that!